# UIActivityIndicatorView ignores color property

Tags: ios

Here is my code for initializing UIActivityAndicatorView:

```
self.indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    self.indicator.color = [UIColor colorWithRed:252.0 green:113.0 blue:9.0 alpha:1.0];
    self.indicator.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:self.indicator];
```

After animation started - indicator appears in proper place, but with white color. Why color property is ignored?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The values are floats between 0 and 1. Try this:

```
    self.indicator.color = [UIColor colorWithRed:252.0/255.0 green:113.0/255.0 blue:9.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: @ЕвгенийКравцов Pleas accept the answer to help others who have the same problem.

Comment: Yea - the system will allow me to do that in few minutes

Answer (score 1):

It's important to notice that the `activityIndicatorViewStyle` will override the `color` property as per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityindicatorview/1622836-color):

> If you set a color for an activity indicator, it overrides the color provided by the activityIndicatorViewStyle property.

So you just have to set the style first, then the color:

```
let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .whiteLarge
let myColor = UIColor.colorWithRed(252.0/255.0, green: 113.0/255.0, blue: 9.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
activityIndicator.color = myColor
activityIndicator.startAnimating()
```

And that should be it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm amazed that the selected answer worked in Dec of 2015, since I cannot get the color to show anything but white no matter what I do in iOS 9.2. This for the Large White spinner.

What I did find that works is to start the control with an alpha of 0, then after a 100 milliseconds change the color and show it. The code below is from my ATMHud fork on github:

```
- (void)setActivity:(BOOL)activity
{
    hudView.showActivity = activity;
    if (activity) {
        [hudView.activity startAnimating];
        hudView.activity.alpha = 0;
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
            {
                // Workaround for bug where Apple ignores the color property
                [self changeColor];
            } );
    } else {
        [hudView.activity stopAnimating];
    }
}
- (void)changeColor
{
    hudView.activity.color = [UIColor blackColor];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.250+_animateDuration animations: ^{ hudView.activity.alpha = 1; }];
}
```